# Reading signal strength using CoreBluetooth's readRSSI()

Tags: ios, macos, core-bluetooth

I wonder what exactly happens when you call `readRSSI()` on a *CoreBluetooth* `CBPeripheral`.

In earlier versions of CoreBluetooth, the `rssi` property
was always(?) populated automatically. This has been deprecated
for some years now and I wonder why.

Or ­– in other words ­– will periodically [i.e. every 500ms] calling
`readRSSI()` to update the RSSI value have any adverse effects with
respect to the BLE bandwidth or power consumption?